# Bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I try to run following command in my terminal:

```sh
bash -c 's="test"; s=$(echo "word1  word2 " | awk '{print $1;}'); echo $s;'
```

It gives me following errors:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
}); echo $s;: command not found
```

The problem does not occur when I save my script in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are passing to bash with -c uses single quotes. This will "protect" the inner double quotes, but will not work to protect the quotes used to hide '$1' in the `awk` program.

From bash Man

> ```
> Enclosing  characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
> each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur between 
> single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
> ```

Given that only a single character need to be quoted, Consider using double quotes for the `awk` program, and escaping the '$'

```
bash -c 's="test"; s=$(echo "word1  word2 " | awk "{print \$1;}"); echo $s;'

Output:
word1
```